# Automatically generating a diagram of function calls in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dependencies, code-analysis, diagram

Anybody knows of a tool that can be used to automatically build [diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagram) of function calls in MATLAB?

E.g. For a given function, the tool would recursively go through function calls and build a 2D graph where nodes would represent functions and directed edges would connect calling functions with called functions.

Ideally the tool could allow the user to turn on and off filters to only include user-defined functions, limit the depth of recursion, etc.

I believe [Doxygen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen) provides some similar functionality for more traditional [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) languages, but I was wondering if something like this exists already for MATLAB.

Thanks!

Comment: Although there are no tools I know of to create the *diagram*, there have already been a number of questions on how to find function dependencies in MATLAB (the output of which could potentially be used to create graphic representations): [How can I generate a list of function dependencies in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95760), [MATLAB: determine dependencies from 'command line' excluding built in dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592680), [Matlab: how to find functions on path that use a given function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629294)

Comment: as I mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421447/call-graph-generation-from-matlab-src-code/7444630#7444630), you can use the [M2HTML](http://www.artefact.tk/software/matlab/m2html/) toolbox (in fact, it also uses GraphViz to generate call graphs)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the techniques from those other answers referenced in gnovice's comment to get a list of function dependencies as (A,B) pairs, where A calls B. Then install [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and use it to generate the diagrams. You can create the .dot files from Matlab with something like this.

```
function createFunctionDependencyDotFile(calls)
%CREATEFUNCTIONDEPENDENCYDOTFILE Create a GraphViz DOT diagram file from function call list
%
% Calls (cellstr) is an n-by-2 cell array in format {caller,callee;...}.
%
% Example:
% calls = { 'foo','X'; 'bar','Y'; 'foo','Z'; 'foo','bar'; 'bar','bar'};
% createFunctionDependencyDotFile(calls)

baseName = 'functionCalls';
dotFile = [baseName '.dot'];
fid = fopen(dotFile, 'w');
fprintf(fid, 'digraph G {\n');
for i = 1:size(calls,1)
    [parent,child] = calls{i,:};
    fprintf(fid, '   "%s" -> "%s"\n', parent, child);
end
fprintf(fid, '}\n');
fclose(fid);

% Render to image
imageFile = [baseName '.png'];
% Assumes the GraphViz bin dir is on the path; if not, use full path to dot.exe
cmd = sprintf('dot -Tpng -Gsize="2,2" "%s" -o"%s"', dotFile, imageFile);
system(cmd);
fprintf('Wrote to %s\n', imageFile);
```

[image]

GraphViz works great for lots of other tree and graph applications, like class inheritance and dependency trees, data flow, and so on.

Comment: +1 for turning me onto GraphViz. Thanks for the link!

Comment: +1 for providing an intuitive example!

Comment: This may help, https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27608-graphviz-like-tools-for-matlab

Comment: Is GraphViz applicable with Octave or is there something else similar?

Comment: Sure. GraphViz is an external program. All the Matlab code is doing with GraphViz is generating a text file that contains a "DOT" format document for GraphViz to read. If you can get the function dependency data in Octave, then you could produce a DOT file in the same way.