# What is the purpose of non-static methods in MATLAB?

Tags: oop, matlab, static

Since MATLAB [does not provide self-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5637015/321973), what is the actual difference between a static and a non-static method in MATLAB, apart from the latter not being call-able without a class instance? One always has to pass a reference to the object-to-be-modified anyway (**edit** apart from setters, getters and [overloaded operators](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/br02znk-1.html) which implicitly include the self-reference)

Comment: Interesting remark. Only difference I can think of is when your class inherits `handle`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For non-static methods, Matlab provides the calling class as the first argument.  By (personal convention) I call this argument `self`, which then emulates a self reference syntax.  e.g.:

```
methods (Static = false)
    function output = someMethod(self, arg1, arg2, arg3)
        self.x      %Now refers to the (potentially private) field `x`
        self.someOtherFunction(arg1, arg2) %Calls another method, which may be static or not.
    end
end
```

By contrast

```
methods (Static = true)
    function output = someStaticMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3)
        %There is no input appropriate to the name "self" 
        someOtherFunction(arg1, arg2) %Calls another method, which must be static
    end
end
```

Given an object `someObject`, these methods can both be called by using:

```
someObject.someMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3)
someObject.someStaticMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

---

The self-reference discussed in the linked question is referring to package names, which is an entirely different animal.

Comment: ah, I misunderstood this, so MATLAB _does_ have some kind of `this` object, only it is explicitly named in the method definition (but _not_ passed in the function call). Thanks! Now this does actually make sense

Comment: It can be passed in the function call, depending on whether you call it using object or functional syntax. Using @Pursuit's example, you could type either `someObject.someMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3)' or someMethod(someObject, arg1, arg1, arg3)'. Both are typically equivalent, and the equivalence maybe illuminates why MATLAB method signatures are as they are.

Comment: Those calling forms are typically equivalent, but it's the case where they aren't that probably explains why there's no implicit `this`. If you use the dotless `someMethod(someObject, arg1, arg2)` syntax, the method dispatch object doesn't have to be the first argument. You could call `someMethod(arg1, arg2, someObject)` instead. The method called depends on the runtime types of all the arguments, and their superiority relationships. With multiple dispatch like this, there's not necessarily a single method dispatch object that would be used for an implicit `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps more relevant is that static methods can be called without invoking the objects constructor: i.e., if class foo has static method bar, then foo.bar() invokes static method bar without the constructor foo() ever having been invoked.