# How to get the fully-qualified name of the currently executing function?

Tags: matlab, package, octave, introspection

Suppose I have:

```
+MyPackage/+MySubPackage2/some_function.m
```

How can I generate the string `'MyPackage.MySubPackage2.some_function'` from within this `some_function.m` when it's executing?

- `mfilename()`, `dbstack()`, `what()`, etc. all just give `'some_function'`
- `meta.package.fromName` requires the string we're after as its input
- parsing the full path (`mfilename('fullpath')`) or `meta.package.getAllPackages()` etc. seems to be the only way...

Seems that calling `mfilename('class')` in a `class` inside a `package` gives the right answer, but there's no equivalent for plain functions...

...or is there? Feels like I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: Don't you know the name of the file you're editing when you write a function? :p

Comment: @CrisLuengo ...there are times when indeed I haven't the foggiest 

Comment: How about `dbstack ('-completenames')`?

Comment: @jrook nope, `S=dbstack ('-completenames'); S.name` just gives `some_function`

Comment: The full path is stored in `S.file`.

Comment: @jrook Indeed. I can also get the full path using `mfilename('fullpath')`, but that's not what I'm after - I'm looking for the exact string you'd need to type into the MATLAB command line to call that function.

Comment: The interesting part would be why you need this info. Perhaps the underlying problem could be solved without this?

Comment: @Andy I "need" if for the same reasons you "need" `mfilename` or `argv[0]` or `__name__` etc.: Resilience against renaming. Consistent help text generation. Reusable code that works correctly without any change in different packages. etc. Indeed, perhaps, for my immediate problem, I can do away with the need, but at this point it's just curiosity! Why is there such rich introspection everywhere, but not when packages are thrown in the mix...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is possible to import the containing package (say p1/p2), then:

```
function outputArg1 = some_function()
import p1.p2.*
t = @some_function;
func2str(t)
%ans  = 'p1.p2.some_function'
outputArg1 = ...;
end
```

The method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13371343/2928853) may also be used (with some changes possibly) to automate the import process.

Comment: I guess this is the best I'm gonna get, considering the answer you linked to (thanks for that link!) The problem with your solution is: move this function to `+p14/+p45` and the code breaks. So indeed it seems, there is just no way to generate that string without parsing the full-path string...sounds like The MathWorks have a hole to fill 