# `localfunctions` inside a package

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, package, function-handle

[localfunctions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/localfunctions.html) returns function handles to all the local functions in an m-file. However, this doesn't work in a package. For example, the following code saved as 'a.m' runs fine:

```
function fs = a()
    fs = localfunctions;
end

function babo()
end

function hidden()
end
```

Called from MATLAB console:

```
>> a()

ans = 

    @babo  
    @hidden
```

But when it is inside a package as '+aaa/b.m', I get nothing:

```
>> aaa.b()

ans = 

     {}
```

I don't think this behavior is well documented. How do I overcome this?
I need to use `localfunctions` to [unit test](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-function-based-unit-tests-.html) some functions within the package and I don't want to keep it outside of the package just because of this.

Comment: Clarifying question: Are you trying to expose the local functions of a package function in order to explicitly test those local functions themselves, or are you trying to write the test itselt as a function residing in a package using this api:http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-function-based-unit-tests-.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to import the package before calling `localfunctions`:

#### +mypkg/mytest.m

```
function f = mytest()
    import mypkg.*
    f = localfunctions;
end

function foo()
end

function bar()
end
```

When called:

```
>> f = mypkg.mytest()
f = 
    @foo
    @bar

>> functions(f{1})
ans = 
     function: 'foo'
         type: 'scopedfunction'
         file: 'C:\Users\Amro\Desktop\+mypkg\mytest.m'
    parentage: {'foo'  'mytest'}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is less than ideal because you have to hard-code the package name inside the function (related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5637015/97160, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5635413/97160)

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in R2013b and R2014a where localfunctions does not respect the package of the file containing the local functions. This bug has been reported to The MathWorks for fixing in a future release.

Until then, Amro's workaround is the best option.

EDIT: This has been fixed in release R2014b.