# Getting the full path of the function calling the constructor

Tags: matlab, oop, constructor, eval

I'd like the constructor of a class to automatically determine the full path to the calling function, so that that class can write a file that's guaranteed to be in the caller's directory (instead of whatever happens to be the `pwd()`).

So, I have the following setup:

In `some_path/test.m`:

```
function test    
    SomeClass()    
end
```

In `some_path/some_subdir/SomeClass.m`:

```
classdef SomeClass < handle    
    methods
        function obj = SomeClass()            
            evalin('caller', 'mfilename(''fullpath'')')
        end
    end    
end
```

When I call `test()`, I get the following:

```
>> test()
ans = 
    'some_path/some_subdir/SomeClass.m'  % <- ...why?
```

I expected the call to `mfilename()` in `evalin('caller', ...)` to evaluate inside `test()`, but apparently, that doesn't happen...

Nesting `evalins` doesn't seem to help:

```
...
function obj = SomeClass()            
    evalin('caller', ' evalin(''caller'', ''mfilename(''''fullpath'''')'') ')
end
...

>> test()
ans = 
    'some_path/some_subdir/SomeClass.m'
```

The only way to get this to work is the far less intuitive `dbstack()`:

```
...
function obj = SomeClass()            
    S = dbstack(1, '-completenames');
    S(1).file            
end
...

>> test()
ans = 
    'some_path/test.m'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: whats wrong with dbstack? anyway, its better if you directly pass this information to the class. thats the point in arguments.

Comment: Interesting! I learned something new here!

Comment: @MendiBarel there's nothing _wrong_ with `dbstack`, it's just that I expected `evalin` to behave differently...a bit of context: I'm writing something akin to a  `pickle` in Python: a class that automatically and completely transparently buffers certain variables that take a long time to compute, to a file. For that sort of thing, you don't want to bother the user with having to provide path information _by default_; the most intuitive path for that file should just _be_ the default. There are legit use cases for `eval*` 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you cannot use `evelin` for this purpose. From [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html):

> `evalin('caller', expression)` finds only *variables* in the caller's workspace; it does not find *functions* in the caller.

From that I read that not the full context of the calling function is recovered before evaluating the expression, only variables in the workspace of the calling function are made available.

That same documentation page also mentions this limitation:

> `evalin` cannot be used recursively to evaluate an expression. For example, a sequence of the form `evalin('caller', 'evalin(''caller'', ''x'')')` doesn't work.

That is consistent with the notion that only the caller's workspace is made available, not the full context. The expression is not actually evaluated as if it were written inside the calling function.

I have repeated your experiment with a simple M-file function, just to verify this indeed is not specific to classes or constructors, but generally applies to any function, anywhere.

The `dbstack` option is the way to go.

Comment: I thought that line from the docs meant that it can't see functions local to the caller's context (nested functions, subfunctions, etc.), but that something built-in like `mfilename` should still work...I guess you're right.