# Track number of times a function is referenced within a folder/file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, refactoring, dependencies

I have a large project going with 40+ functions and it's just increasing every day. Often times I reference a function multiple times from different scripts. Every once in a while, I'll find that I need to edit a function for one script, and then I realize that it's possible that I want that function to stay the same for another script. Obviously this in itself is no problem; I can just write a new function. But sometimes I don't remember if I've referenced that function anywhere else in my larger folder containing all my scripts!

Is there a way in MATLAB to somehow find a count of how many times a function is used within a folder? If so, is there a way to track where it's being referenced from? Thanks in advance =).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this I typically use the *find files* funcionality  (found in the menu on top of your screen)  with the 'contains' option. Especially if your function name does not match common variable names this works very well.

Just search in the entire matlab path, or in the specific directory for something like `myFun(` and you will see all the places where it is called. In the worst case you will also find some places where it is not called.

Comment: This is perfect! I knew MATLAB would have something to do this, they have pretty good user interfaces =p. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Totally overlooked this. Damn you, new Matlab user interface ;)

Answer (score 5):

MATLAB provides support for dependency tracking using the [`depfun`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/depfun.html) function. `depfun` tells you which other functions are required to run a given function.

What you're asking is the opposite problem: Which functions require a given function?

Using `depfun`, you can do a reverse lookup. Here's a quick example:

```
function result = invdepfun(allFunctions, lookFor)
% Return all functions that depend on a given function
%
% Example: invdepfun({'myfun1', 'myfun2', 'myfun3'}, 'myfun4') returns all of
% 'myfun1', 'myfun2', 'myfun3' that use 'myfun4'.

    filename = which(lookFor);

    result = {};
    for i = 1 : numel(allFunctions)
        deps = depfun(allFunctions{i}, '-quiet');
        if any(strcmpi(deps, filename))
            result{end + 1} = allFunctions{i};
        end
    end
end
```

You can use various other MATLAB functions (`which`, `dir`, etc.) to autmatically compile a list of all your functions to pass to `invdepfun` as the first argument.

See also [this post on File Exchange](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/09/30/determine-file-dependencies/).

Comment: Like the FEX submission, but can this also show you how many times a function is called from each function?

Comment: Definitely useful as well =)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: My solution will only show you which functions use your function, not how often they reference it. As far as I can see, this also holds for the FEX submission. You can get the absolute number of runtime calls using the output of `profile('info')`, but that's something different. Why do you need this number?

Comment: @FlorianBrucker it would give a first indication of how much you would have to refactor each function that calls your dependant function. I wouldn't say you need it, but it would have been a nice extra.

Comment: [M2HTML](http://www.artefact.tk/software/matlab/m2html/), as part of the docs it generates, also produces a list of other function which references the current one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7444630/97160

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: In that case I'd go with a simple heuristic of simply searching how often the name of the target function occurs in the code, similar to your answer. You can use `invdepfun` to find the relevant functions first.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any builtin Matlab functionality that does this, so you probably have to write some function to do this for you.

You could use the [DIRWALK](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32036-dirwalk-walk-the-directory-tree) function from Matlab FileExchange to crawl your project folder and look into all Matlab files (use the `what` command) searching for your function name.