# links between pieces (functions, routins, vars, etc) of a code?

Tags: performance, matlab, profiling, lint

Is there any program that draws something like a diagram between all functions, modules, etc in a program in the repository? For example, in [this](https://github.com/Christiaanvandertol/SCOPE) Matlab repository the function called `SCOPE.m` calls a set of functions. I wonder whether there is any way to map the structure of this repository and map the links between functions, dependencies, etc.

EDIT:
In the comments, the profiler was mentioned, but as we can see from the link provided for Matlab code ([HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421447/call-graph-generation-from-matlab-src-code)), as an example, using the profiler is a bit tedious. I am hoping that there is some sort of tool that can give us the code structure (say from a repo on GitHub) regardless of the programming language.

Comment: You sort of have this kind of representation by running your code with the [profiler](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html). When you click on a function, it gives you its parents and children functions (A bit tedious nut this might be a starting point)

Comment: If you want to do that programmatically, I believe you could do something with the output of the [profile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) function, in particular its field `FunctionTable`. If you want to map the entire program you would have to run it several times to cover all the paths the program can take through the functions

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think I got the main idea which is using the profiler, but I was hoping that there are some sort of tools that can do it automatically, say from a github repo. The matlab code is great tho!