# Why is depfun(fun) returning 'too many output arguments' (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, dependencies

depfun's documentation gives the following:

> [list,builtins,classes] = depfun(fun) returns the MATLAB classes that
>   fun requires.

Excellent, this is exactly what I want. However, when I call that on my function it tells me there are too many output arguments. So, I tried

`list = depfun(Dynamo)`

and to my surprise the same error occurred. How can this be? depfun(Dynamo) must return at least one argument, no?

What I'm trying to do is to create a dependency graph in the way as suggested by [Andrew Janke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105904/andrew-janke) in [Automatically generating a diagram of function calls in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518200/automatically-generating-a-diagram-of-function-calls-in-matlab)

The following works and gives me a nice report, but I don't want the graph to contain all the hidden functions which is why I'm opting for depfun.

> profile on
>   Dynamo;
>   profile off
>   profview

Any insight is much appreciated

Comment: Dynamo = http://www2.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/wpol/html/toolkit/DynaMo_vers2.html ?

Comment: No, Dynamo = http://haaslab.github.io/dynamo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the function argument as a string

```
>> [list,builtins,classes] = depfun( 'Dynamo' )
```

Comment: Thank you, sadly I've tried that before and it leads to matlab getting stuck to the point that only restarting it will solve the issue. I was silly enough to assume this meant my input was incorrect. I now know that this is because depfun is very slow for large complicated programs. 

To get around this I've found the following: 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17291-fdep-a-pedestrian-function-dependencies-finder

Highly recommended.