# Is it possible to generate a flow diagram from MatLab code?

Tags: matlab, uml

I have inherited a MatLab project with a bunch of MatLab files I need to refactor. It'd help me a lot to be able to generate a flow diagram or similar. I've Googled it and found other people asking the same question years ago, but nothing recent that works. This is the most recent thread about it:

- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/28195-automatic-tool-to-generate-sequence-and-class-diagrams-uml

I've seen there is some documentation about [a tool to generate class diagrams](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44742-umlgui) from MatLab code, but unfortunately the code I have is not OO.

Any ideas would be really appreciated :-)

Comment: You might find some ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518200/automatically-generating-a-diagram-of-function-calls-in-matlab)

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be marked off-topic for not being about programming. There are certainly ways to accomplish this in code as the links from the OP and the answer linked to by @il_raffa clearly demonstrate. The OP is not asking to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource" in the question.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193006/is-there-a-way-to-map-the-program-execution-order-in-visual-studio-or-matlab/52200985) is a similar question which has a satisfactory answer to this one if it's acceptable to map actually executed flow as opposed to all references in the codebase.