# Generate flowchart of Matlab code

Tags: matlab, flowchart

Despite searching on mathworks site, I did not succeed in finding some way that can generate a flow chart of the matlab .m program file.

Do anybody know any clue about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to generate a flow diagram from MatLab code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646351/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-flow-diagram-from-matlab-code#comment49358540_30646351).

Comment: Would you llike to implement it yourself? Because the parsing tree of the code is retrieved by `mtree`. Here's some info: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/function-definition-meta-info

Comment: If you have money to spend, [visustin](http://www.aivosto.com/visustin.html) works well.