# Is there a way to "map" the program execution order in Visual Studio or MATLAB?

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, debugging, visual-studio-2012, uml

What I mean by "map" is that I have a "main" function which calls many other programs inside, and I want to be able to see which file runs first, second, third, etc. Basically, I want to be able to see the list and order of dependencies in this large OOP design program (which the creator did not make a UML class diagram for) to help decipher the code. Surely such a functionality must exist in popular IDE's? I'm mostly dealing with C++ and MATLAB so I'm more concerned with these two specifically, but please list any IDE's you know of that have this functionality. I'd prefer something visual and not just running through a debugger and breakpoints a thousand times.

Answer (score 4):

In MATLAB, I don't believe there's a built-in way to do this visually, but you can get the information you need from the profiler using the `FunctionTable` returned by [`profile('info')`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html#f8-618415-p).

The parent/child relationships in the table essentially define a directed graph which you can interact with visually or otherwise in MATLAB if you convert it to a `digraph` object.

For example, to map the program execution of `kmeans`:

```
profile on
kmeans(rand(100,2),5);
p = profile('info');
t = struct2table(p.FunctionTable);
g = digraph(false(height(t)), t); % Create the graph with nodes and no edges

% Add the edges
for ii = 1:g.numnodes
    for jj = 1:numel(g.Nodes.Children{ii})
        g = g.addedge(ii, g.Nodes.Children{ii}(jj).Index);
    end
end

plot(g,'NodeLabel',g.Nodes.FunctionName,'Layout','layered');
```

Produces:
[image: <code>plot(g,'NodeLabel',g.Nodes.FunctionName,'Layout','layered');</code>]

The file each function comes from is also accessible via the `FileName` field of the `FunctionTable` so if the distinction between functions and the files they came from is important you could use this information to color or simplify the graph accordingly.

Comment: Great answer thank you! However, is there a way to show only the user defined functions in this list? I'm more interested in mapping only the user defined functions because I just ran this code with my program and the result is unreadable due to the sheer amount of function names in it since it lists the built-in functions as well. I want to get rid of the clutter and map only the functions I have defined. This may not be doable I realize.

Comment: The `FileName` property for all builtin functions will start with a different path to the ones in your program; so it could be as easy as dropping nodes in the graph where the `FileName` doesn't look right. However if using any builtin functions that take function handles you might have to be a bit cleverer, as this will break the connectivity between the function that passed the handle and the function the handle references.

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest way be to just check the Type field by inserting -->
for(....)
if (p.FunctionTable(i).Type == 'Java-method'
Then Skip over putting this on the graph.....


I'm basically just trying to get rid of all Java method calls. I want M-script, M-method, and M-anonymous functions. Would this work? where would you recommend I insert this if statement relative to your code above?

Comment: Please also if you can explain why you think it's easier to parse 'FileName' field instead of the 'Type' field.

Comment: If you just want to get rid of Java method calls that's fine, but most builtin features present as regular M-files residing on early entries on the MATLAB path. To remove the Java calls you can add `g = g.subgraph(~strcmp(g.Nodes.Type,'Java-method'));` after the graph edges have been added. It's much easier in general to construct the graph in full and then reduce it because the indices in `FunctionTable.Children` are indices from that full list, so once entries are removed you'd start having to transform them to create the right graph edges.